# How to match overlapping instances in Regex Expressions

Tags: python, regex

Let's say that I have an input string `-1 acho coisa direitos direitos ah` and I intend to replace `direitos` by a given ID, let's say `13` so that string outputed is  `-1 acho coisa 13 13 ah`

Current state is as follows

```
pattern = r"\s" + re.escape(token) +  r"\s"

token_id_output = ' ' + token_id + ' '
content = re.sub(pattern, token_id_output, content)
```

It happens that this solution only matches and replaces the first instance as the `re.sub()` method is non-overlapping by default. The lookahead operator `(?=...)` is sugested to mitigate this problem but can't seem to find the proper usage in this case. Any ideas how to properly implement overlap matching?

Comment: Use `pattern = r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(token))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `\b` to mark word boundaries, not `\s`:

```
In [41]: re.sub(r'\bdireitos\b', '13', '-1 acho coisa direitos direitos a')
Out[41]: '-1 acho coisa 13 13 a'
```

Comment: I was but `\b` was catching unintended strings like `traz-me` which is a valid Portuguese term.